# Editing 375 posts simultaneously? Maybe from the database?

Tags: posts

I have a question regarding my site, tablified.com. I need to change a line of code on ALL of my posts. Within each post, there is a certain line of code that needs to be altered. This code is this:

> [a href="https://market.android.com/details?id=COM.NAMEOFAPP.EXAMPLE>< src="http://tablified.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/androidicon.png" alt="" title="Click to Download from Android Market" width="300" height="48" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4507" /]

This is found at the bottom of every post. As you know, this simply displays a clickable picture that takes the user to another page. For all 376 posts, 95% of this code is the same. The only thing that differs between posts is:

```
COM.NAMEOFAPP.EXAMPLE
```

that line is specific for every app on the official Android  Market. I have found a new plugin that will allow me to display a widget at the bottom of the post with a nice picture and link to the official Android Market. To make a long story short, that entire line of code needs to be edit to look like this:

```
[app]COM.NAMEOFAPP.EXAMPLE[/app]
```

All I did was remove the first part of the code:

```
<a href="https://market.android.com/details?id=
```

and replace it with [app] and then replace the second half of the code

```
">< src="http://tablified.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/androidicon.png" alt="" title="Click to Download from Android Market" width="300" height="48" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-4507" /></a>
```

with `[/app]` so now you are left with

```
[app]COM.NAMEOFAPP.EXAMPLE[/app]
```

of course with the proper name of that particular app in between the `[app][/app]`. My question is, what is the quickest way to accomplish this? If I export all the posts to a XML file, I can use a text editor to make the changes. But what will happen once I import this file back into Wordpress? Will it overwrite the previous posts? Will it create new ones? What will happen to the screenshots with each of those posts? I am using a theme that doesn't actually attach the image to post, meaning if I export it, the pictures wont be there. Will they be lost? Please let me know if you can help me with this. Thank you so much for your time. I hope everything made sense. The fix seems simple, but I am not sure of the outcome.

Ayman

Answer (score 4):

[Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/) is a good plugin to be able to search and replace with Grep through all posts and pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in number of ways, but easiest would be to use one of tools available. For example [Serialized PHP Search Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).

Be sure to create backup of your database before you start to make any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Search and Replace Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace). I think it will do what you want.